# How to create a Blazor Web App .NET 8 (SSR) project with Authentication using CLI?

Tags: .net, blazor, .net-8.0

I am trying to set up authentication for a Blazor Server-Side Rendering (SSR) application, but I'm encountering an issue when using the dotnet new command with the --auth option. Here's the command I'm trying to run:

```
dotnet new blazor --auth individual
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: Invalid option(s):
--auth
   '--auth' is not a valid option
individual
   'individual' is not a valid option
```

It appears that the --auth option is not recognized for Blazor SSR projects. How can I add authentication to a Blazor SSR application? Is there a different approach or set of commands I should be using?

Thank you for your assistance!

Comment: the problem is `blazor` is not a valid command you need to choose `blazorserver` or `blazorwasm`

Comment: In .NET 8, there is a new template called Blazor SSR; it's a different template, not Blazor Server or Blazor WebAssembly. You can find more details about it in this link: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-preview-5/#new-blazor-web-app-project-template

Comment: Ah ok didn't know that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For what it is worth, it looks like Individual account auth option was added to the .NET 8 SSR template in VS 2022 17.8.x latest or .NET8 RC2 of SDK.

Answer (score 4):

### .NET 8 RC2

Edit: Oct 10, Visual Studio 2022 v.17.8 Preview 3 update includes the [.NET 8 Release Candidate 2](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-rc-2/).

This supports [individual accounts](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-dotnet-8-rc-2/#identity) authentication type using the following command.

```
dotnet new blazor -au Individual
```

[image]

---

### .NET 8 RC1

There is no authentication template available for **.NET 8**, Blazor Web App RC1. project template at the moment.

[image]